# Why does it require no more than 1 + logN compares when inserting a new node into a heap?

Tags: algorithm, heap, heapsort

I think when inserting a new node into a heap, the amount of nodes it might passes by is logN, why is it (1 + logN), where is 1 from?

Comment: Because `log(1) = 0` but inserting into a heap with 1 element takes a comparison

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is necessary to account for the border case when the number of notes is 2<sup>n</sup>. A heap of n levels fits 2<sup>n</sup>-1 objects, so adding one more object starts the new level:

[image: Heap]

Black squares represent seven elements of a three-level heap. Red element is number eight. If your search takes you to the location of this last element, you end up with four comparisons, even though log<sub>2</sub>8 is three.

Comment: thanks for your answer But I don't understand why there are 4 comparisons. For me, it seems only 3 times even if the new added red square swims up to root (three comparisons: red line, green line and blue line, 3 times in total)

Comment: @user1888955 You need to compare to the root, root's child, root's grandchild, and the red node itself, to ensure that you have found the item that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :) i missed comparison on the node itself.